# Tilt Effect for HubTile

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I added the `TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled` property to my `HubTile`:

```
<toolkit:HubTile toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Title="title" Message="This is message" x:Name="name" DisplayNotification="False" Source="pB.png" Tap="tap" />
```

I also added the `HubTile` type to the `TiltableItems` collection in the page's constructor, per the :

```
public HubPage()
{
    TiltEffect.TiltableItems.Add(typeof(HubtTile));
}
```

but the HubTile don't have tilt effect....

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try adding your `HubTile` as Content of `HyperLinkButton` or `Button` which supports `TiltEffect`

Add a `Style` to `PhoneApplicationPage.Resources` which works for `Button` and `HyperLinkButton` that adds support for other controls as `Content`

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EmptyButtonStyle" TargetType="primitives:ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="primitives:ButtonBase">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Also add the primitives namespace to the page

```
xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows"
```

Then use your `HubTile` as `HyperLinkButtons`'s (or `Button`) `Content` like this

```
<HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource EmptyButtonStyle}">
    <toolkit:HubTile toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Title="title" Message="This is message" x:Name="name" DisplayNotification="False" Source="pB.png" Tap="tap" />
</HyperlinkButton>
```

This will finally support `TiltEffect` and `HubTile`

Answer (score 0):

Get `TiltEffect` from [Updated Tilt Effect - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/11/updated-tilt-effect.aspx)
OR download the Silverlight Toolkit Source from [Silverlight Toolkit - Downloads](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases) 
and then add the `HubTile` class to the list of 'tiltableItems' in `TiltEffect.cs`:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Default list of items that are tiltable
    /// </summary>
    static List<Type> tiltableItems = new List<Type>() { typeof(ListBoxItem) , typeof(HyperlinkButton) , typeof(HubTile) };
```

If you decide to modify the Toolkit, be sure to build the project on Release, and target the .dll you create inside your own application.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. Check the date on the code. The tilt effect in the Silverlight Toolkit is a better implementation.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen don't make assumptions :) but whatever, download the silverlight toolkit and update it there instead. I'll edit the original post

Answer (score 0):

I've found other simple solution that works great when `HubTile` is used as `ListBox.ItemTemplate`.

Simply set `TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"` on ListBox and `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on `HubTile` and voila - it works :) You can still respond to `HubTile` clicks through `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event and `HubTile` has working tilt effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hubtile by default is not added to TiltableItems List and needs to be added manullay... 
Add the following code to codebehind

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             TiltEffect.TiltableItems.Add(typeof(HubTile));
            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
```

and add the following line to your hubtile or grid containing the hub tile

```
<phone:PanoramaItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="item3" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
```